# how to avoid accidentally killing text in emacs?

Tags: emacs, text-editor, elisp

I have a highlighting mode (forget what it's called) that shows me, through highlighting the text, what region I have selected between mark and point. this comes in very handy when killing regions. However, sometimes, even when no text is visibly highlighted but i accidentally press C-w it still occasionally kills some text. My question is how do i stop this behaviour? I only want it to kill text IF i've highlighted it.

Comment: InRe close votes: since the answer seems to be in elisp, I think that SuperUser is probably *not* the best place for this. It should stay here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define your own function and override the key-binding:

```
(defun my-kill-region ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (call-interactively 'kill-region)
    (message "Region not active, didn't kill")))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'my-kill-region)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
M-x transient-mark-mode
```

will keep the region highlighted even after you start typing, and when you use C-Space to set mark. Then you'll see what C-w will kill.

Answer (score 6):

Set the variable `mark-even-if-inactive` to `nil`.  That way, you can only kill text if it's actually highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Press C-Space (set-mark-command) just before C-w to set the mark at the cursor position so that there is no text between the mark and cursor position to kill.

Comment: So before accidentally pressing C-w, one should accidentally press C-space?